# Select within select subquery takes too long

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables :

1. 60.000 record Invoice
2. 100.000 record Exchange Rate based on current date
3. 25 record Currency Symbol

`table_invoice`:

```
+-----------+-------------+----------+--------------+
| invoice_id | currency_id | amount   | invoice_date |
+------------+-------------+----------+--------------+
|          1 |      2      |     10   | 4/28/2016    |
|          2 |      3      |     30   | 4/29/2016    |
|          3 |      4      |     50   | 4/30/2016    |
|          4 |      2      |     40   | 6/18/2016    |
|          5 |      6      |     25   | 6/20/2016    |
|          6 |      7      |     87   | 6/25/2016    |
|          7 |      4      |     100  | 6/29/2016    |
|          8 |      9      |     45   | 7/14/2016    |
|          9 |      2      |     71   | 9/27/2016    |
|      60000 |      3      |     430  | 1/18/2017    |
+------------+-------------+----------+--------------+
```

and

`table_exchange_rate`:

```
+-----------------+-------------+---------------+--------------------+
| exchange_rate_id | currency_id | exchange_rate | exchange_rate_date |
+------------------+-------------+---------------+--------------------+
|              1   |          2  | 13.352        | 4/25/2016          |
|              2   |          3  | 10.195        | 4/25/2016          |
|              3   |          4  | 14.390        | 4/25/2016          |
|              4   |          5  | 1.720         | 4/25/2016          |
|              5   |          6  | 118           | 4/25/2016          |
|              6   |          7  | 9.468         | 4/25/2016          |
|              7   |          2  | 13.125        | 6/15/2016          |
|              8   |          3  | 10.520        | 6/25/2016          |
|              9   |          4  | 14.800        | 6/25/2016          |
|              10  |          5  | 1.800         | 6/25/2016          |
|              11  |          6  | 120           | 6/25/2016          |
|              12  |          7  | 9.320         | 6/25/2016          |
|           100000 |          7  | 9.500         | 6/25/2016          |
+------------------+-------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

and

reference_currency:

```
+-----------------+---------------+-----------------------+
| currency_id      |currency_symbol| currency_name         |
+------------------+---------------+-----------------------+
|              1   |          USD  | US Dollar             |
|              2   |          AUD  | Australian Dollar     |     
|              3   |          EUR  | Euro                  |
|              4   |          HKD  | Hong Kong Dollar      |
|              5   |          JPY  | Japan Yen             |
|              6   |          SGD  | Singapore Dollar      |
|              7   |          MYR  | Malaysian Ringgit     |
|              8   |          CHF  | Swiss Franc           |
|              9   |          THB  | Thailand Baht         |
|              10  |          GBP  | Great Britain Pounds  |
|              11  |          SEK  | Swedish Krona         |
|              12  |          CNY  | China Yuan            |
|              25  |          SAR  | Saudi Arabian Riyal   |
+------------------+-------------+-------------------------+
```

When I run:

```
SELECT
a.invoice_id AS 'INVOICE_ID',
a.currency_id AS 'CURRENCY_ID',
a.amount AS 'AMOUNT',
a.invoice_date AS 'INVOICE_DATE',
(
SELECT b.exchange_rate FROM table_exchange_rate b
WHERE b.exchange_rate_date <= a.invoice_date AND b.currency_id = a.currency_id
ORDER BY b.exchange_rate_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS 'EXCHANGE RATE'
)
FROM table_invoice a
```

Result:

```
`+------------+-------------+----------+--------------+--------------+
| INVOICE_ID | CURRENCY_ID | AMOUNT   | INVOICE_DATE | EXCHANGE_RATE |
+------------+-------------+----------+--------------+---------------+
|          1 |      2      |     10   | 4/28/2016    | 13.352          
|          2 |      3      |     30   | 4/29/2016    | 10.195
|          3 |      4      |     50   | 4/30/2016    | 14.390
|          4 |      2      |     40   | 6/18/2016    | 13.125
|          5 |      6      |     25   | 6/20/2016    | 118
|          6 |      7      |     87   | 6/25/2016    | 9.320
```

`

and the result works fine but it is very slow(approximately > 60sec) with 60k record(table_invoice) looping on 100k record(table_exchange_rate) finding exchange rate at the current date,

If invoice_date can't match with exchange_rate_date or the user doesn't input the exchange rate on the app, it will using exchange rate the latest record already in input before the current date (`b.exchange_rate_date <= a.invoice_date AND b.currency_id = a.currency_id`)

Can I speed up this query or there any other options? Thank you..

Comment: using joins is usually faster than running subqueries

Comment: show us the EXPLAIN of your query **EXPLAIN SELECT
a.invoice_id AS 'INVOICE_ID',
a.amount AS 'AMOUNT',
(
SELECT b.exchange_rate FROM table_exchange_rate b
WHERE b.exchange_rate_date <= a.invoice_date AND b.currency_id = a.currency_id
ORDER BY b.exchange_rate_date DESC LIMIT 1) AS 'EXCHANGE RATE'
)
FROM table_invoice a;**

Comment: The EXPLAIN on its own isn't much help. We normally need to see SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for each of the relevant tables too. That said, correlated subqueries like this generally perform more poorly than their non-correlated counterparts.

Comment: And see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query too!!

Comment: Show the table definitions,not sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Try same thing with `JOIN`

```
select a.invoice 'invoice_id', a.currency_id 'curency_id', a.amount 'amount', a.invoice_date 'invoice_date', ter.exchange_rate ' exchange_rate'
from table_invoice ti
left join table_exchange_rate ter on ter.currency_id = ti.currency_id and ter.exchange_rate_date <= ti.invoice_date
```

Comment: Doesn't look like the same thing to me. And `LEFT JOIN... <=` is not a realistic construct.